# Как связать два блока при помощи carousel или slick?

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel, slick.js

https://prnt.sc/lrf12s

Есть картинке есть section в которой 2 блока взаимосвязанные между собой, и должны переключаться вместе, можно подключить owl-carousel или slick....но как связать эти два блока при помощи js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `slick` есть конфигурация **sync**

```js
 $('.slider-single').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: true,
  fade: false,
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  infinite: false,
 useTransform: true,
  speed: 400,
  cssEase: 'cubic-bezier(0.77, 0, 0.18, 1)',
 });

 $('.slider-nav')
  .on('init', function(event, slick) {
   $('.slider-nav .slick-slide.slick-current').addClass('is-active');
  })
  .slick({
   slidesToShow: 7,
   slidesToScroll: 7,
   dots: false,
   focusOnSelect: false,
   infinite: false,
   responsive: [{
    breakpoint: 1024,
    settings: {
     slidesToShow: 5,
     slidesToScroll: 5,
    }
   }, {
    breakpoint: 640,
    settings: {
     slidesToShow: 4,
     slidesToScroll: 4,
   }
   }, {
    breakpoint: 420,
    settings: {
     slidesToShow: 3,
     slidesToScroll: 3,
  }
   }]
  });

 $('.slider-single').on('afterChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide) {
  $('.slider-nav').slick('slickGoTo', currentSlide);
  let currrentNavSlideElem = '.slider-nav .slick-slide[data-slick-index="' + currentSlide + '"]';
  $('.slider-nav .slick-slide.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
  $(currrentNavSlideElem).addClass('is-active');
 });

 $('.slider-nav').on('click', '.slick-slide', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let goToSingleSlide = $(this).data('slick-index');
  $('.slider-single').slick('slickGoTo', goToSingleSlide);
 });
```

```css
body { background-color: #aacccc }

.js .slider-single > div:nth-child(1n+2) { display: none }

.js .slider-single.slick-initialized > div:nth-child(1n+2) { display: block }

h3 {
 background: #f0f0f0;
 color: #3498db;
 font-size: 2.25rem;
 margin: .5rem;
 padding: 2%;
 position: relative;
 text-align: center;
}

.slider-single h3 {
 line-height: 10rem;
}

.slider-nav h3::before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 75%;
}

.slider-nav h3 span {
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.slider-nav .slick-slide { cursor: pointer; }

.slick-slide.is-active h3 {
 color: #c00;
 background-color: #fff
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

<div id="page">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="column small-11 small-centered">
   <h2>Slick Slider Syncing</h2>
   <div class="slider slider-single">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
    <div><h3>6</h3></div>
    <div><h3>7</h3></div>
    <div><h3>8</h3></div>
    <div><h3>9</h3></div>
    <div><h3>10</h3></div>
   </div>
   <div class="slider slider-nav">
    <div><h3><span>1</span></h3></div>
    <div><h3><span>2</span></h3></div>
    <div><h3><span>3</span></h3></div>
    <div><h3><span>4</span></h3></div>
    <div><h3><span>5</span></h3></div>
    <div><h3><span>6</span></h3></div>
    <div><h3><span>7</span></h3></div>
    <div><h3><span>8</span></h3></div>
    <div><h3><span>9</span></h3></div>
    <div><h3><span>10</span></h3></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Также есть `sync` в  [**owl-carousel**](https://jsfiddle.net/owcfjaht/)